# Java EE @Resource isn't mapping to web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations

I am trying to develop a web application with a java back end but I need to track if the tasks are complete and I am using the `ManagedExecutorService` for this.

I am trying to use the `@Resource` annotation to inject a `ManagedExecutorService` as follows.

```
@Resource(name = "myExecutionService")
private ManagedExecutorService mExecutionService;
```

web.xml:

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>myExecutionService</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

but I keep getting an error saying that I am missing the "Services with missing/unavailable dependencies"

```
13:52:31,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-threads - 158) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "tbm-core-1.0.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"tbm-core-1.0.war\".WeldService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"tbm-core-1.0.war\".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [TestBedManager] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private com.shenick.teravm.core.ws.TestBedManagerWebService.testBedManager]"},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"tbm-core-1.0\".\"tbm-core-1.0\".env.myExecutionServicejboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.myExecutionServiceMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"tbm-core-1.0\".\"tbm-core-1.0\".env.myExecutionServicejboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.myExecutionService]"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the problem and it's because ManagedexecutorService is java 7 only apparently and jboss 7.1.1 will not deploy apps that use threads.

to solve this I will need to upgrade to EAP 6.1 (new name for jboss).

Comment: Well done on working that out. A thorny problem! Two things, though: firstly, EAP 6.1 isn't the new name for JBoss, it's a particular commercially supported release of JBoss. The new name for JBoss is WildFly. Secondly, there are other ways to get worker threads in EE 6, which is what JBoss AS 7 supports. The best is probably to use [asynchronous invocation on EJBs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html). You can send code off to run in a background thread, and get a `Future` back to tell when it's done, which is similar to what an `Executor` gives you.

Comment: Cheers for the reply dude but I'll just use the appropriate versions of JBoss and Java because it's a newly started project (thankfully) so no other dependencies on legacy releases :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want just use the default implementation, use

```
@Resource(mappedName="java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorService")
```

In this case, you don't need to specify it in web.xml.

If you want to use your own implementation, I think you should configure your application server resources first (set it with your implementation).

EDIT:

I found this by chance:
[How to Configure Scheduled Tasks in Wildfly](http://blog.chris-ritchie.com/2013/09/how-to-configure-scheduled-tasks-in-wildfly..html). It could help you, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude, I tried your suggestion but I still get the same error. I am using JBOSS application server can you elaborate a bit on configuring the resources first?